# React route direct access not working, but working with navlink

Tags: javascript, reactjs

the contents of app.js

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div className='App'>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Routes>
          <Route path='/*' element={<CustomerLayout />} />
          <Route path='/admin/*' element={<AdminLayout />} />          
        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
}
```

and contents of CustomerLayout.js

```
const CustomerLayout = () => {
  return (
    <div>
    <MainHeader />
    <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Home />}></Route>
        <Route path="/shop" element={<Shop />}></Route>
        <Route path="/product-detail/:slug" element={<ProductDetail />}></Route>
        <Route path="/cart" element={<Cart />}></Route> 
        <Route path="/login" element={<Login />}></Route>       
    </Routes>
    <MainFooter />
    </div>
  )
}
```

now when I try to access mydomain/shop from the menu, it is working fine.
code for menu is like this
`<NavLink to='/shop'>Shop</NavLink>`
but if try to access the page directly mydomain/shop
I get 404 not found error.
what I am missing here.

update:
index.js modified as suggest in answer by Bret.

```
import React from 'react';
import { createRoot } from 'react-dom/client';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { persistor,store } from './store/store';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import './index.scss';
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import { PersistGate } from 'redux-persist/integration/react';

const container = document.getElementById('root');
container.classList.add("i-wrap");
const root = createRoot(container);


root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Provider store={store}>
    <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={persistor}>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <App />
      </BrowserRouter>
      </PersistGate>
    </Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>
);   

reportWebVitals();
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a file in your public directory titled `_redirects`

In that file all you need is

```
/* /index.html 200
```

save that then try again, should work now

Comment: still getting same error.

Comment: Your BrowserRouter needs to be wrapped around all your routes. It looks like your Customerlayout component doesn't have the BrowserRouter wrapped. I would wrap my App in the index file with BrowserRouter. Then place ALL the routes I'm the App component.

Comment: Hi Bret, can you add an example, I tried as per your suggestion, but still no success.

Answer (score 0):

All Codes was just fine as was posted originally.
all I needed is to place a `.htaccess` file in public folder before build with content like

`FallbackResource ./index.html`

and Everything got fixed.

Note:
Bret has tried a lot to help, but it didn't help. But I think it is not his fault, as I didn't mentioned that the application is being deployed on Apache server.